# Copy site root libraries and sub libraries with all permission using Get-PnPSiteTemplate

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Our SharePoint sites have yearly structure like 2024->subfolders->Files. When I use below PowerShell code to copy existing site template to new site then I am getting only root folders created. Each root folders have six subfolders. Any help on how I can duplicate exact same existing site to new site except files using PowerShell.

```
$ExistingSiteUrl = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/Archive/"
$SiteTemplateFile = "\Template.xml"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $ExistingSiteUrl 
Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out $SiteTemplateFile -force

#Create New Site
$newurl = New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title "Test Root Archive" -Alias "Archive1"
$TargetSiteUrl = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/Archive1"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $TargetSiteUrl 
Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate -Path $SiteTemplateFile
```

I tried above PowerShell code to generate template with all configurations.